# Select more on Mac doesn't work, but select less does

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, selection-tools

I'm trying to do select more like on Windows where you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and it selects more from where you have selected faces/vertices/edges and so on, but it doesn't work, however selecting less works perfectly.

I have *Emulate Numpad* option turned on, does it have something to do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to preferences -> keymap -> key-binding and search for "+". Looks like you have something else referenced to same key.

[image]

If this doesn't work, please provide screenshots of your search result for "mesh":

[image]